# Python and SQLQueries

Tags: python, sql

This might be a basic question but I can't seem to get the output of the python/sql statements I write. For example, when type the following,

```
from sql import *
from sql.aggregate import *
from sql.conditionals import *
user = Table('user')
select = user.select()
tuple(select)
```

I don't see the output (i.e the records) of these statements in the console. Why is this? When I type  `tuple(select)`  in the shell, I get the following as output:

```
('SELECT * FROM "combine2" AS "a"', ())
```

Note that I am using the  `sql`  module.

Comment: What  module(s) are you using for SQL?

Comment: @ScottHunter that's [`python-sql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql) library.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, [`python-sql` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql), which you are using, is for *creating/generating SQL queries only*. In order to execute them, you need to use a **database driver**. E.g. in case of SQLite:

```
import sqlite3

# ...
statement = user.select()

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(statement)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: When I type cursor.execute(tuple(statement)) or cursor.execute(statement)...it doesn't work.

Comment: @Damien wait, what do you mean by "does not work"? Do you fetch the results afterwards like in my sample? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that the argument to `sqlite2.connect` is the correct path to your database file (by checking the value returned, of course).